# Que ciclo puedo utilizar para que a determinada hora se haga una funcion?

Tags: c#, visual-studio

Estoy intentando hacer que después de 9 de la noche mi programa ejecute una función especifica, pero que sea solo una vez. Estoy probando de la siguiente forma:

```
do
        {
            AbrirFormInPanel(new Pedidos());
            //if (time == true)
            //{
            InitializeTimer2();
            InitializeTimer();
        } while (DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay > new TimeSpan(09, 47, 00) && DateTime.Now.TimeOfDay < new TimeSpan(09, 49, 00));
           MessageBox.Show("fUNCIONA");
```

Al iniciar el programa inmediatamente me muestra funciona a pesar de que no es la hora de la condición. Que podría ser?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Buen dia, no dices que funcion, pero supongamos que quieres enviar un correo:
Para la hora de ejecucion el unico parametro es hora de envio,

```
 static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            //hora de envio
            var HoraEnvio = "11:00:00";
            var partesHoraEnvio = HoraEnvio.Split(new char[1] { ':' });

            var fechaHoraActual = DateTime.Now;
            var fechaHoraEnvio = new DateTime(fechaHoraActual.Year, fechaHoraActual.Month, fechaHoraActual.Day,
                       int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[0]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[1]), int.Parse(partesHoraEnvio[2]));
            TimeSpan ts;
            if (fechaHoraEnvio > fechaHoraActual)
                ts = fechaHoraEnvio - fechaHoraActual;
            else
            {
                fechaHoraEnvio = fechaHoraEnvio.AddDays(1);
                ts = fechaHoraEnvio - fechaHoraActual;
            }

            //espera TS tiempo y ejecuta la funcion.
            Task.Delay(ts).ContinueWith((x)=> EnviarCorreo());

            Console.Read();
        }

        static void EnviarCorreo()
        {
            Console.WriteLine("Enviando correo...");
                //aqui la implemntacion del envio de correo
        }
```